# maven-archetype-quickstart create Maven Project with Java5

Tags: java, maven

When i try to create a Maven Project using the following command:

mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=[your project's group id] -DartifactId=[your project's artifact id] -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart

JRE set to 1.5 as default. I want to have JRE 7 as default for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used an archetype, but if all you want to do is to change the Java version used to compile, just add this to your POM, under `<plugins />`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Or the equivalent `property` short version:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```